Skype doesn't response after typing all my information
I am trying to use skype program.
First I typed my outlook mail and then typed my password.
Then the skype doesn't response like this. I have tried it for several times. I also installed different versions of skype but the result was same.

Sorry, StackOverflow is for programming questions only
